# Call public sub each day at specific time without reopening the file again

Tags: vba, excel

I have this public sub defined in Module 1 of my excel workbook

```
Public Sub AutoUpdate()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("22:40:00"), "GetTime"
End Sub
```

And in my workbook code i have this to call this AutoUpdate method.

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call AutoUpdate
End Sub
```

My problem is that when i open the file it ways the time to be 22:40:00 and it calls `"GetTime"` but then on the next day the excel either crashes or the function is not called again.
Is this `Application.OnTime method`  working for each day without needing to reopen ( refresh ) the workbook again.

Comment: If you are doing this for any thing worth of any importance. JUST DON'T DO IT.  This is the worst way to schedule jobs.

Comment: its important can you suggest how to to it then ?

Comment: One way would be to create a vb script to call/execute the excel macro.  Then schedule that vbs through windows scheduler.

Comment: I just have to call GetTime on specific time of the day and each day how to schedule this GetTime using windows scheduler

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov How to schedule your task via Windows Task Scheduler would probably be a good question to ask on the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call DailyRun
End Sub
```

DailyRun code:

```
Sub DailyRun()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("22:40:00"), "GetTime"    
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:59:00"), "DailyRun"
End Sub
```

The *DailyRun* macro calls itself at the end of each day to create new Ontime event.

If you want to run the macro using Windows **Task Scheduler**, add your macro to Workbook Open event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnTime TimeValue("22:40:00"), "GetTime"
  Me.Close
End Sub
```

Don't forget to close your workbook.

Comment: why to close the workbook i might want to still operate it.

Comment: If you want to use your approach and use Task Scheduler to open a file everyday, you need to close the file and let the TaskScheduler open the file again and call the Workbook_Open event. If you open a file that is already open, Workbook_Open event will not be called.

Comment: ill use the first method. but I dont like to close the excel since im doing stuff on it and i need it opened.